# Extracting contents from a header and parts of payload

Tags: python, regex, awk, sed, scripting

I have the following contents from **data.log** file. I wish to extract the ts value and part of the payload (after deadbeef in the payload, third row, starting second to last byte. Please refer to expected output).

**data.log**

```
print 1: file offset 0x0
ts=0x584819041ff529e0 2016-12-07 14:13:24.124834649 UTC
type: ERF Ethernet
dserror=0 rxerror=0 trunc=0 vlen=0 iface=1 rlen=96 lctr=0 wlen=68
pad=0x00 offset=0x00
dst=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff src=ca:fe:ba:be:ca:fe
etype=0x0800
45 00 00 32 00 00 40 00 40 11 50 ff c0 a8 34 35         E..2..@.@.P...45
c0 a8 34 36 80 01 00 00 00 1e 00 00 08 08 08 08         ..46............
08 08 50 e6 61 c3 85 21 01 00 de ad be ef 85 d7         ..P.a..!........
91 21 6f 9a 32 94 fd 07 01 00 de ad be ef 85 d7         .!o.2...........


print 2: file offset 0x60
ts=0x584819041ff52b00 2016-12-07 14:13:24.124834716 UTC
type: ERF Ethernet
dserror=0 rxerror=0 trunc=0 vlen=0 iface=1 rlen=96 lctr=0 wlen=68
pad=0x00 offset=0x00
dst=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff src=ca:fe:ba:be:ca:fe
etype=0x0800
45 00 00 32 00 00 40 00 40 11 50 ff c0 a8 34 35         E..2..@.@.P...45
c0 a8 34 36 80 01 00 00 00 1e 00 00 08 08 08 08         ..46............
08 08 68 e7 61 c3 85 21 01 00 de ad be ef 86 d7         ..h.a..!........
91 21 c5 34 77 bd fd 07 01 00 de ad be ef 86 d7         .!.4w...........

print 3806: file offset 0x592e0
ts=0x584819042006b840 2016-12-07 14:13:24.125102535 UTC
type: ERF Ethernet
dserror=0 rxerror=0 trunc=0 vlen=0 iface=1 rlen=96 lctr=0 wlen=68
pad=0x00 offset=0x00
dst=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff src=ca:fe:ba:be:ca:fe
etype=0x0800
45 00 00 32 00 00 40 00 40 11 50 ff c0 a8 34 35         E..2..@.@.P...45
c0 a8 34 36 80 01 00 00 00 1e 00 00 08 08 08 08         ..46............
08 08 50 74 73 c3 85 21 01 00 de ad be ef 62 e6         ..Pts..!......b.
91 21 ed 4a 8c df fd 07 01 00 de ad be ef 62 e6         .!.J..........b.
```

**My expected output**

```
0x584819041ff529e0,85d79121
0x584819041ff52b00,86d79121
0x584819042006b840,62e69121
```

**What I have tried so far**

I am able to extract the ts value. I used

```
 awk -v ORS="" '$NF == "UTC"{print sep$1; sep=","} END{print "\n"}' data.log
 >> ts=0x584819041ff529e0,ts=0x584819041ff52b00
```

But didn't succeed in extracting the payload contents.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The string `86d79121` is not there in your log file sample. How is it part of your expected output?

Comment: There are two instances of `de ad be ef` in your log file? How do you expect  it to be distinguished?

Comment: Hi Inian, it is there in the log file. please check that after (first) deadbeef in the payload you can find it.

Comment: Agreed, refer my next comment? How do you expect your needed string to be distinguished, when there are two occurrences of the same.

Comment: The value after first deadbeef is what I need. We can ignore the second one.

Comment: There are 3 input blocks but only 2 lines of expected output. Why? Is `deadbeef` always entirely on one line or can it be split across lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to get it done:

```
awk -F '=| ' '/^ts=/{printf $2","} /de ad be ef/{if(!a){printf $15$16;a=1}else{print $1$2;a=0}}' data.log
```

Output:

```
0x584819041ff529e0,85d79121
0x584819041ff52b00,86d79121
```

Explanation:

```
-F '=| '                 : set the field seperator to both '=' and 'space'
/^ts=/{printf $2","}     : if pattern 'ts=' found at line beginning, print the second field
/de ad be ef/{something} : if pattern 'de ad be ef' found, do 'something'
```

Initially variable `a` will be equal to `0`. if pattern `de ad be ef` is found for the first time, `if(!a)` would succeed and hence print the `15th` and `16th` fields. Now set `a` to `1`. So when `de ad be ef` pattern is matched in the next line, `if(!a)` check would fail and hence print the `1st` and `2nd` fields. Now, reset `a` to `0` and continue the same process for the rest of the file.

Comment: can you also give some details on what the code does ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the details. The reason was that your command was failing for test case 3 (added to the question). Thanks

Comment: check it now.. it was because /ts/ was matching 'Pts' in the 3rd set's case

Comment: Never do `printf $2`, always `printf "%s",$2`. The former tells awk to use the input data as a format specifier and so will fail cryptically when the input contains formatting characters like `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want sed:

```
sed -n -e '/^ts/ {s/^ts=\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)/\1/; H;};' \
       -e '/de ad be ef/ {N; s/\(.*\)de ad be ef \([0-9a-f]\+\) \([0-9a-f]\+\) \(.*\) \([0-9a-f]\+\) \([0-9a-f]\+\) \(.*\)/,\2\3\5\6/; H;};' \
       -e '$ {x; s/\n,/,/g p;}' file
```

If you are interested in further infos, just ask.

Comment: Thanks. For larger entries, your solution seems to take a long time than the accepted answer.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines that is all. For anything else you're using constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented and, as seen here, an awk solution will be clearer, faster, more portable, more easily extensible and be better in almost every other desirable attribute of software.

Answer (score 1):

awk variant using deadbeef as switch

```
awk -F '[= ]' '/^ts/{s=$2",";a=15} /de ad be ef/{s=s $a $(a+1);if(a==1)print s;a=1}' data.log
```

and a sed variant

```
sed -n -e '/^ts=/{h;b^J}' -e "/de ad be ef/,//{H;g;s/ts=\([^ ]*\).*\n*de ad be ef \(..\) \(..\).*\n\(..\) \(..\).*/\1,\2\3\4\4/p;}" data.log
```

info: "`^J`" is a *CTRL+J* (new line carractere) in posix version and a "`;`" in GNU version

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS= '{
    gsub(/(  |\t)+[^\n]*(\n|$)/," ")
    print gensub(/.*\nts=(\S+).*de ad be ef (..) (..) (..) (..).*/,"\\1,\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6",1)
}' data.log
0x584819041ff529e0,85d79121
0x584819041ff52b00,86d79121
0x584819042006b840,62e69121
```

The above will work even if deadbeef is split across lines.